# The Colliders of Navmesh Agents are Slipping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, navmesh

I have a npc prefab to be spawned a certain amount from it at the beggining of the game. They chase player, patrol, and escape from the player depending on the situation. As far as I can observe only when they escape from the player, the colliders are not where they should be. I can't understand the problem. I'm also not sure what information I should give in order to better explain the problem to you. please help me.

[Here is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxNDO.png)

[Another pic with hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0cH9.png)

Comment: possibly down to the animation?

Comment: Would help if you shared how those objects look in the hierarchy.

Comment: @BugFinder I don't quite understand but are you saying that the problem might be related to animations?

Comment: @AntônioPedro I'm not sure if this is what you're hoping to see, but I've added one more pic.

Comment: animations dont necessariy "move" the character just makes it perform the action.. this leaves the colliders behind